# error unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.List to type System.Linq.IQueryable

Tags: vba, odata

My code is :

' GET: odata/Event_Game_Schedule

```
    <EnableQuery>
    Function GetEvent_Game_Schedule() As IQueryable(Of Event_Game_Schedule)
        Dim schedule As New List(Of Event_Game_Schedule)
        schedule = db.Event_Game_Schedule.ToList()
        For Each x As Event_Game_Schedule In schedule
            x.hometeamid = (From t In db.Teams Where t.id = x.hometeamid Select t.name).FirstOrDefault
            x.visitorteamid = (From t In db.Teams Where t.id = x.visitorteamid Select t.name).FirstOrDefault
        Next

        Return schedule.AsQueryable.ToList()
    End Function
```

what am I doing wrong .. this is a controller and I want to return the names of the teams instead of the teamid in the API.

thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like VBA - since when has VBA had things like `List(Of ...)`, and `Return`?  Do I need to dig out my manual and brush up on the changes in the latest versions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I needed only to add the ASQueryable part .. not the .ToList()

this is visual Basic for a vb.net project